# Default c++ project which is setup using autoconf

Tags: autoconf, automake

I know this is not a programming question so someone might close this but I am struggling hard in setting up a simple c++11 project using autoconf. I want a src and obj directory for source and object files. I also want a recursive directory structure. Went through many links but facing a hard time on this. What I wana achieve is have a Project directory then a src and obj directory in that Project directory which will have sub directories for each components. Just thought of asking if there exists some default project which I can download and then use it for my purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with automake.  It doesn't let you choose where the object files go.

Instead you can configure and build in a parallel tree.  That is what many GNU developers do.  This way the sources and objects are separated.

Comment: Can you explain how to configure and build in a parallel tree?

Comment: The usual thing is something like: cd $srcdir/..; mkdir build; cd build; ../src/configure && make